# What is the lowest item level that can be achieved through the Reduced Requirements affix?

Tags: diablo-iii

I want to know what the lowest possible item with this affix is and how much the requirements are reduced.

I found that the maximum values seems to be [18](http://diablo.incgamers.com/blog/comments/item-affix-quick-look-chart), but I guess this only goes for ilvl 63.

Comment: I remember searching around for this, I think the lowest level it can show up in is a level 30 item, but can't confirm other than just looking in the AH, and it was only up to -5 or so

Comment: Found one item with *Level Requirement reduced by 15*...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of Patch 1.0.5, affixes roll based on the monster's ilvl, not the ilvl of the item itself.  From the [Patch Notes](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/patch-notes/1-0-5): "Affixes on items will now roll their level based on the level of the monster killed rather than the item's level (this applies to all items including random affixes on Legendary and set items)"

[This page](http://www.d3own.com/affix-list/all-slots/generic/level56/148/) has tables which list various affixes and the item level for that affix.  With an item that is level 35, you can get up to 5 reduced level requirement, which is the lowest item level that has the "reduced level req" affix.

Here is the table:

```
Mod Text                            Name            Level   Req.Level   
Level Requirement Reduced by (2-5)  of the Squire   35      33  
Level Requirement Reduced by (2-6)  of the Squire   40      38  
Level Requirement Reduced by (2-7)  of the Squire   45      43  
Level Requirement Reduced by (2-8)  of the Squire   50      48  
Level Requirement Reduced by (2-10) of the Squire   55      54  
Level Requirement Reduced by (2-12) of the Squire   60      59  
Level Requirement Reduced by (2-14) of Courage      61      60  
Level Requirement Reduced by (2-16) of Courage      62      60  
Level Requirement Reduced by (2-18) of Courage      63      60
```

Comment: Hey, Andrew, welcome to Arqade!  Can you add the relevant table into your answer, please?  That way, even if the site you linked to no longer has the information, it's still preserved here.

Comment: My wizard has a staff with item level 61 and reduced level requirements by 18. So above might have been true at some point, but not anymore.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that.  I do recall that change, tracked it to way back in Patch 1.0.5, and updated the description.